# open link of google play store in mobile version android

Tags: android, google-play

I have link of my other apps in my latest app, and  I open them in that way.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("url");
Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
startActivity(intent);
```

this code opens the browser version of google play store.

When trying to open from my phone, the phone prompts if I want to use a browser or google play and if I choose the second one it opens the mobile version of google play store.

Can you tell me how can this happen at once? I mean not ask me but directly open the mobile version of google play, the one that I see while open it directly from phone.

Comment: I wish that the second to last paragraph was true for me.  Using the http link found here:  http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html#OpeningDetails does not prompt for the user to choose the app or the browser.  It always assumes the browser.  Unfortunately, I can't use the `market://` protocol either.  Anybody else seeing this behavior?

Answer (score 263, accepted):

You'll want to use the specified `market` protocol:

```
final String appPackageName = "com.example"; // Can also use getPackageName(), as below
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
```

Keep in mind, this will crash on any device that does not have the Market installed (the emulator, for example). Hence, I would suggest something like:

```
final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}
```

While using [`getPackageName()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageName()) from `Context` or subclass thereof for consistency (thanks [@cprcrack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/423171/cprcrack)!). You can find more on Market Intents here: **[link](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent)**.

Comment: Opening the following in the browser does not open Google Play: market://details?id=pandora

Comment: The ID is the package name, not the app name. Try `market://details?id=com.PandoraTV` (assuming [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.PandoraTV) is the app you want).

Comment: Try opening any link that starts with market:// in Chrome for Android.  You will see that it only performs a search result, it doesn't open the Google Play store.  It is irrelevant if the Pandora package name is correct here, I can give you a hundred correct package names and it won't change the issue.

Comment: **This answer is about using the `market://` prefix from your own app, not from a website via the browser.** I can attest to its functionality (on versions 2.3, 3.x, 4.0, 4.1, and 4.2) and it works with the stock browser, Chrome Beta 25, and Chrome 18.

Comment: I got it, thanks.  I would also think that Chrome is considered an app, and it treats market:// specially just like my app would.

Comment: Yes, Chrome is an app, but that would require its makers [Google] to use this code, not the people [you] making the websites. As it stands, this code is to help people who are structuring links specifically from their apps.

Comment: You can use `getPackageName()` to automatically retrieve the app id.

Comment: How to use this link in share message?

Comment: @ツPratikButaniツ I don't think you can. You could try pasting it as a URL with the `market://` prefix, but many parsers would not recognize it. Best to go with the `play.google.com` URL.

Comment: But `play.google.com` Opens in browser and may user dont like to go in browser and open. so any way?

Comment: @ツPratikButaniツ Shares are not always designed to be opened on a mobile device. The link to the Play Store App has to be done in the code of the app where the link is used.

Comment: can we get the response from play store app after redirection ? That the user has clicked installed or app gets downloaded through my redirection ?

Comment: @Gautam No, I'm afraid not.

Comment: but i got to know that the advertisement sdk's are tracking this too.

Answer (score 6):

Below code may helps you for display application link of google play sore in mobile version.

For Application link :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + mContext.getPackageName());
Intent myAppLinkToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

  try {
        startActivity(myAppLinkToMarket);

      } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

        //the device hasn't installed Google Play
        Toast.makeText(Setting.this, "You don't have Google Play installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
```

For Developer link :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pub:" + YourDeveloperName);
Intent myAppLinkToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

            try {

                startActivity(myAppLinkToMarket);

            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

                //the device hasn't installed Google Play
                Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "You don't have Google Play installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Android Intents](https://github.com/d-tarasov/android-intents/) library for opening your application page at Google Play like that:

```
Intent intent = IntentUtils.openPlayStore(getApplicationContext());
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: It would be helpful to include a disclaimer that this is your library and [the function is implemented](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.dmitriy-tarasov/android-intents/1.1.0/com/dmitriy/tarasov/android/intents/IntentUtils.java#IntentUtils.openPlayStore%28com.dmitriy.tarasov.android.intents.Context%29) pretty much the same way as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the *Google Play Store* app is installed and, if this is the case, you can use the *"market://"* protocol.

```
final String my_package_name = "........."  // <- HERE YOUR PACKAGE NAME!!
String url = "";

try {
    //Check whether Google Play store is installed or not:
    this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.android.vending", 0);

    url = "market://details?id=" + my_package_name;
} catch ( final Exception e ) {
    url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + my_package_name;
}


//Open the app page in Google Play store:
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Open app page on Google Play:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + context.getPackageName()));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case, we want purpose to update by linking to the native google play store application :

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
    data = Uri.parse(
            "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.android")
    setPackage("com.android.vending")
}
startActivity(intent)
```

and if we want to open the instant app link here is the purpose kotlin code:

```
val uriBuilder = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details")
        .buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter("id", "com.example.android")
        .appendQueryParameter("launch", "true")

// Optional parameters, such as referrer, are passed onto the launched
// instant app. You can retrieve these parameters using Activity.intent.data.
uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("referrer", "exampleCampaignId")

val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
    data = uriBuilder.build()
    setPackage("com.android.vending")
}
startActivity(intent)
```

Please refer to Android Developer Link : https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play#android-app