# Can you search Google Play using Intent?

Tags: android, search, android-intent, google-play

Here's the situation:
I want to open another app via implicit intent, but the user doesn't have adequate app. Can I open for him "Google Play Search Activity" with results including apps that contain components able to serve such intent (have appropriate intent filter). In other words can you perform search using "Intent data"?

Comment: Answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922762/open-link-of-google-play-store-in-mobile-version-android should be useful for you.

Answer (score 12):

To perform search use search keyword in URI:

```
Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("market://search?q=<Your Search Word>"));
startActivity(goToMarket);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to access Google Play information at this time - the answer is no.

There are some alternative projects that allow API access to get Play market information, but there is no official Play Market API supported by Google at this time.

Comment: AppAware is one of the alternative APIs I was thinking about.  http://dev.appaware.com/

Answer (score 0):

That can be done by URL. You want a generic ACTION_VIEW Intent with a Google Play URL. The Play Store app will accept the Intent.

Examples:

This URL works to perform a search for "twitter" in the store.
https://play.google.com/store/search?q=twitter&c=apps

This URL loads the record for the official Twitter app in the store.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twitter.android