# How to add app download link from Play Store, in my Application

Tags: java, android

How to add app download link from Play Store, in my Application.

Ex. I know the application package name as com.test.abc

I want to provide a link in my application so that when user click that link, the app with package name com.test.abc should get download from play store and install.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922762/open-link-of-google-play-store-in-mobile-version-android

Comment: Thnks for the link @Niek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `market://` protocol inside an `Intent`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+theAPPName));
```