# After my app launches Play Store it returns immediately to the app

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-play

I have the rate app button in the app which lunches Play Store application where the user can rate my app. I'm using standard code:

```
        try {
            String appPackageName = getPackageName();
            Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName));
            startActivity(marketIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

The problem is that from time to time (but not every time), Play Store application closes after few seconds and the phone returns to my application. In this case the user won't manage to rate my app.

Edit

I'm extending SherlockFragmentActivity, using ViewPager and Admob banner. I think it can be conncted with some of them.

Comment: do u have any error log? try it on emulator to and recreate the problem!

Comment: are u using samsung device ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922762/open-link-of-google-play-store-in-mobile-version-android?rq=1

Comment: @Metalhead1247 There was no important logs. I'm trying to reproduce the problem on the emulator but as I said it happens from time to time.

Comment: @PranavJadav Yes, I'm using Galaxy SII, did you have similar problem?

Comment: Apps->settings-> app manager->see your  download manager is enabled or disabled ?

Comment: @PranavJadav I have two build-in apps called "Downloads". Both are enabled. How can this app affect closing Google Play (or returning my app to the foreground)?

Comment: http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-7-tablet-2012/246334-google-play-store-crashes-refuses-open.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
 Context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=" +  appPackageName)));
```

Comment: I'll bet he's got `Context` imported statically, which means he is already doing this.