# How to link android app in facebook api

Tags: facebook

So I have an app that is live on the app store and google play. I have no programming skills so the programmer I hired did all the work. Recently we ran into a road block because we don't know how to direct the users to the google play store when they click on the notification link on an android phone.

Here is a screen shot: http://screencast.com/t/ubiqG4upYz

When the users are on an iphone device. Tt directs them to the app store. We're just trying to figure out how to do the same for android users.

Comment: The market protocol is what you want to use. See this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922762/open-link-of-google-play-store-in-mobile-version-android

Comment: I'll forward it to my programmer. Thank you!