# Opening an app directly on play store

Tags: android, hyperlink, google-play, android-sharing

I am using sharing intent to share my apps link to users via whatsapp,gmail,twitter...etc..

For example if the link is
market://details?id=com.imangi.templerun&hl=en

It just gets posted as plain text and is not clickable.

I tried using http://market.android.com/details?id=com.imangi.templerun&hl=en
   But the user has to choose another option after clicking the link such as OPEN WITH Chrome or Playstore...

What i want to accomplish is once the user clicks, the app should open on the play store...
Any suggestions and help would be grateful ..
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this link at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922762/open-link-of-google-play-store-in-mobile-version-android). You willget answer to your question. market:// is not clickable by default. You need to implement click event for view containing this text.

Comment: I am posting the link to users via whatsapp or gmail.... So i cannot add event handlers for it or use startActivity....... now u can have a better understanding i guess... @seema

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to open url directly in play store:

```
String url = "http://market.android.com/details?id=com.imangi.templerun&hl=en";
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        i.setPackage("com.android.vending");/* Play store package name */
        startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I am posting the link to users via whatsapp or gmail.... So i cannot add event handlers for it or use startActivity... @Vikalp