# Android: Redirect to android app from play store when apk is installed

Tags: android, google-play

I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922762/open-link-of-google-play-store-in-mobile-version-android) to redirect a user from android app to play store to install an apk now I want to redirect the user again to the app when the apk is successfully installed on the device. Is it possible?

Comment: You can check if the app is installed in onresume() and then start the app using http://stackoverflow.com/a/7596063/1025599

Answer (score 1):

I would say that, if it is possible, it would be achieved through [a service, that runs in the background,](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) that would detect the presence of the installed apk (the new app).